# Exporting in .fbx only exports one animation and a single texture

Tags: animation, export, texture-painting

So, I'm working on the design of a 3D character. I already animated it and added the colours to it, it is a very simple character but when I export it to .fbx it only shows the colour of the head and does not show the animation.Sometimes it only shows a single animation. What is the problem?

**Here are some photos.**

[image]

I deleted the full animation, but they were one animation for each object in the character without bones.

[image]

Does anyone know what I can do to solve this issue? I'm new at blender 2.9.

Comment: @Ribbit12 thanks for the edit! you know what is the problem?

Comment: If you are exporting as an fbx you should animate it with an armature.

Comment: @Chris how can I make the armature to be only one but 3 of them move different?

Comment: One armature with bones to control each part of the mesh. One root bone(non-deformable) for the armature and three child bones to animate each of the spheres.